# Angular 5 Filter > Map > Assign image to OpenWeather Object and display on screen doesn't display

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular5

I am trying to populate the images in the forecasts (5 day forecast) by first filtering only the clear weather and then using map to assign the image URL and then in the HTML ask for that for each of the weather items but it doesn't seem to get the source of the image [src] = clearImage.imaging any ideas?

[Here is my editable project on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-erujta)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are creating the new list clearImage and referencing it in the template. I'm also astonished that due to the fact that objects were pass by reference, you actually added 'imaging' into items in forecasts which pass the filter. So you could've still reference them as `[src]="forecast.imaging"` and it'll work.

The correct way however, is to manipulate the api response itself. I'm not sure why you didn't do it this way:

```
this.forecasts.list = this.forecasts.list
        .filter(item => item.weather[0].main.toLowerCase().indexOf('clear') > -1)
        .map(item => {
            item.imaging = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/96/Weather-Sun-icon.png';
            return item;
        });
```